# Can I convert an FAA medical certificate to a Canadian one without visiting an AME?

Tags: medical, canada

I currently hold a first class FAA medical certificate. Can I transfer to a Canadian medical certificate without meeting with a Canadian AME?

> (2) The applicant may obtain a TCCA Medical Certificate as follows:
>
> (i) The applicant may submit either the original or certified copies
>   of FAA medical examination reports directly to the Civil Aviation
>   Medicine Branch of Transport Canada, Headquarters in Ottawa for
>   processing and assessment;

or

> (ii) Applicants may complete an aviation medical examination by a
>   person who is considered to be a medical examiner with the authority
>   to conduct aviation medical examinations pursuant to CAR 404.16

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question a little and added quotes where I think you were quoting some document. If I got it wrong please edit again as needed!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert an FAA medical certificate directly into a Transport Canada medical certificate. However, you can obtain the Transport Canada medical certificate on the basis of the original or certified copies of FAA medical examination reports by submitting them directly to the Civil Aviation Medicine Branch of Transport Canada, Headquarters in Ottawa for processing and assessment. If they are deemed acceptable, the certificate would be issued in Canada without having to start the process with a Canadian AME. For more information, see [Transport Canada Advisory Circular (AC) No. 401-001, "Application Guidelines for Aeroplane FAA to TCCA Licence Conversion Agreement".](http://www.tc.gc.ca/en/services/aviation/reference-centre/advisory-circulars/ac-401-001.html)

Comment: then just simply send FAA medical examination reports to Branch of Transport Canada? I've tried to contact them, it is really hard to contact them.

Comment: Follow the instructions of section 7 of the document for which I provided a link. Here is a direct link to section 7. And if this answer provides the info you needed, don't forget to accept the answer. :) http://www.tc.gc.ca/en/services/aviation/reference-centre/advisory-circulars/ac-401-001.html#toc70